# Pipe file content into PowerShell command without loading the entire file to memory

Tags: windows-10, memory, powershell, pipe

I've recently started using PowerShell, hoping to never miss [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) again.

I want to restore an instance of a [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database. In Bash, or in the old command prompt, I would type:

> psql --username=... db_name < backup.sql

In PowerShell I found I needed to this:

> Get-Content backup.sql | & psql --username=... db_name

The problem is that backup.sql is big - larger than the amount of RAM on my machine. [Get-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) first reads the file to memory and only then sends it to `psql`.

This is a problem.

How can I simulate the behavior of `<` in PowerShell?

Comment: 5.0 - The one that comes with Windows 10.

Comment: This is just awful. Doesn't Powershell support concurrent reading and pushing into a pipe?

Comment: While this question is absolutely on topic here, I think you would receive more answers on stackoverflow

Comment: I'm not sure it's on-topic there.

Comment: The powershell pipeline is different to regular console app stdin. I don't know the details, but maybe two don't work with each other as nicely as one would hope. What is the content of the backup.sql file? I wonder if it could be broken up into individual sql statements that could be fed into psql. Another idea: Does it work any better in cmd.exe?

Comment: It works well with the old command prompt, and that's what I ended up using.

Comment: If this is part of a script, you can call cmd.exe from PowerShell.

Answer (score 15):

PowerShell's `Get-Content` is less efficient with large files. Boost its performance using the `-ReadCount` parameter to define the batch size for line processing. In the example below, it is set to a value of `500` lines per batch for improved efficiency. Read more about [Get-Content](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx).

#### PowerShell v 5.0 Example

```
Get-Content -ReadCount 500 backup.sql | & psql --username=... db_name
```

#### PowerShell Legacy Version Example

```
Get-Content -Read 500 backup.sql | & psql --username=... db_name
```

---

**Alternatively, consider exploring the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3) command**.

#### PowerShell v 5.0 Example (using `-RedirectStandardInput` switch)

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version>\bin\psql.exe" '--username=... db_name' -RedirectStandardInput backup.sql -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately this causes very strange behavior. Memory usage jumps up and down, and the computer becomes quite sluggish (it's a brand new quad-code i7 with 16GB of RAM).

Comment: @zmbq I think unfortunately you may need to look at other options than Get-Content as this seems to be the root cause of the sluggish performance I think since the file is so huge and the way it reads into memory, etc.  If psql handles `< ` better than PowerShell, you should be able to utilize it and still use PowerShell with the -RedirectStandardInput switch.

Comment: +1 for the solution with `Start-Process -RedirectStandardInput` as it also works for binary input in contrast to piping the result of `Get-Content`.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I simulate the behavior of < in PowerShell?

Check my answer to this question: [PowerShell's pipe adds linefeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32981504/4424236)

> Here is my `Invoke-RawPipeline` function (get latest version from
>   [this
>   Gist)](https://gist.github.com/beatcracker/931613a94a1988d17b31).
>
> Use it to pipe binary data between processes' Standard Output and
>   Standard Input streams. **It can read input stream from file/pipeline
>   and save resulting output stream to file.**
>
> It requires [PsAsync module](http://psasync.codeplex.com) to be able
>   to launch and pipe data in multiple processes.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue I created a powershell cmd.exe process with the executable parameters

```
$cmdArgs = @('/c','psql.exe','--username=...', .. , 'dbname' , '<', 'backup.sql' )
&'cmd.exe' $cmdArgs
```

Worked perfect for what I was trying to do