# Importing a large .dump file into Postgres Database (Win 10)

Tags: powershell, database, postgresql, out-of-memory

I'm running into a problem where I want to import a really, really large .dump file (530gb) into a postgres database inside a docker.

This is the commmand I'm running inside Powershell:

```
cat .\dbexport.dump | docker exec -i my_timescaledb psql -U my_username -d my_relation
```

After ~5min running, my RAM overflows and the running script crashes.

Task Managers shows 99% workload on the powershell window. This is the error message:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
```

Google says, I may should limit the RAM usage for powershell windows like this:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 8192
```

unfortunately, it didn't help at all. Powershell window is still using 99% of RAM available.

(Yes, I restarted WSMan and even my computer)

Is there anything else I could do to finally import my Database?

Comment: But this is not a PowerShell code or feature issue. Based on your use case, you'd have this same memory issue regardless of the scripting language/shell you are using. Essentially, you are doing a bulk upload of data and your defined environment has to be physically optimized for that, or you need to look into chunking (splitting the data) into smaller parts and processes. Docker is running this, the fact that you launched the in PS, does not make it PSCode, or PS performance issue. There are fundamental considerations that must be understood when dealing with large files. Parallel process..

Comment: What did your search for, relative to the environment requirement, and expectations? --- 
['processing large postgress sql uploads'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27processing+large+postgress+sql+uploads%27&t=h_&ia=web), [powershell 'processing large postgress sql uploads'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell+%27processing+large+postgress+sql+uploads%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: @David114 ... see if this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/988275/pipe-file-content-into-powershell-command-without-loading-the-entire-file-to-mem/988288#988288 which I wrote a similar answer to a long time ago.

Comment: I fixed it by switching from windows to linux.
Took ~8-10 hours, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions for me was to run the command in linux instead of windows.
If you have a similar problem, but can't switch to linux, you may have a look at this:

[Pipe file content into PowerShell command without loading the entire file to memory](https://superuser.com/questions/988275/pipe-file-content-into-powershell-command-without-loading-the-entire-file-to-mem/988288#988288)